# Why is qualifier not getting set when running SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am trying to intergation test a function getAccounts in class FDAccounts.java. restTemplate varible in FDAccounts is set using a Qaulifier, the bean is created in other class AccountBeans.java

```
@Service
class FDAccounts{

     @Autowrired
     private ApplicationProperties appProperties;

     private RestTemplate restTemplate;

     public FDAccounts(@Qualifier(accountRestTemplate) RestTemplate rt){
           this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
     }

    public void getAccount(){
       // I am using restTemplate to make the call
       restTemplate.exhange(.... // ***restTemplate is null when running test***
    }

}

@Configuration
class AccountBeans{
  @Bean
  public RestTemplate accountRestTemplate(){
        //code
        return RestTemplate
  }
}
```

I have below test class. When running the test, accountBeans variable is null in FDAccounts class, also variables in ApplicationProperties are not set. I have application-test.yml in test/resources/application-test.yml

```
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application-test.yml")
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
class TestFDAccounts{
 
   private FDAccounts fdaAccounts;


   @Before
       public void setup(){
   }


   @Test
   public void getAccounts(){
     fdaAccounts.getAccounts()...
   }

}
```

Problems

1. restTemplate from AccountBeans is not set in the constructor of FDAccounts when running the test
2. Properties are not set in ApplicationProperties

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing new code it would also be good to use JUnit5 and use @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class) instead of @RunWith

be aware that most of the imports and annotations changed from JUnit4 to 5.
https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration

Comment: Hi, @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)  has not worked for me and using RunWith(SpringRunner.class) , CommandLineRunner in my main class is called, that's what initiates all the beans, and that's why my test works.

Comment: sry for the late answer.
why do you have a main class to start a test? if you are just executing the test in an usual way the SpringExtension or the SpringRunner should take care about the beans for you (depending on the ContextConfiguration you set either in SpringBootTest or in an @ContextConfiguration annotation).